# my plotting of geom_sf has a quite strange scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

```
thefts_fil %>% ggplot() +
geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, color = classification), alpha=0.5, inherit.aes = F) + 
coord_sf(expand = FALSE) + theme_void() + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("grand" = "#CC6699", "petty" = "#009966"), 
name = "Theft Category", labels = c("Grand", "Petty")) + 
labs( title = "Thefts in Chicago (Jan. & Feb. 2020)", 
caption = "Source: City of Chicago Data Portal") + 
coord_sf(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

First time to use `geom_sf()`, I am quite confused about the situation. The axis of y is fine, but the x-axis is extremely short.

Comment: thefts_fil %>% ggplot() + geom_sf(aes(geometry=geometry,color=classification),alpha=0.5,inherit.aes = F)+
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)+
  theme_void()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grand"="#CC6699","petty"="#009966"),
                     name="Theft Category",
                     labels = c("Grand", "Petty"))+
  labs(
    title = "Thefts in Chicago (Jan. & Feb. 2020)",
    caption = "Source:  City of Chicago Data Portal"
) +coord_sf(expand = FALSE)

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).